# How to customize JQGrid with another new header

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

First of Thanks a lot to all who shared great answers in many quesioned asked by many users. I got a lot of information from those answers.

I am trying to implement JQGrid in my project. And as per the requirement I am trying to add an extra header which would look like this:
[image]

I did that by this:
var t1 = '   HighMediumLow ';
            var applyChangesDiv = document.createElement("div");
            $(".ui-jqgrid-hbox").after(t1);

Now my question is this correct way of adding the new header.
So here is my requirement:

> User selects one or more rows and change the priority in the third line of header, then the selected value should apply in the selected row cells.

Note: Here I am referring the 1st row header as Scorecard Name, Priority etc. and the 3rd row is the row which I want add.

Now If I add like I said, I have to write a lot code to apply the changed values in cells and one more issues is when re-sizing the column width, the 3rd row does not re-size.

If I could get a demo, that would be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. instead of adding it after ui-jqgrid-hbox, I added after ui-search-toolbar.

So the new code is:
$(".ui-search-toolbar").after(t1);